# parsing delay in netbeans 6.*

Tags: java, javascript, netbeans, netbeans6.8

How can i set automatic parsing delay in netbeans 6.8

I have a js file which is 1000+ lines and it takes 10s of continuous processing in my triple core 4gigs machine

before i can continue typing.

I found [this](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/netbeans_5_5_6_0) blog but this is for ver 5.5

I have found clearing cache and restarting can speed up things...does that make any diff...

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the list of avaiable plugins there is one called "Scan on Demand" that does what you're asking about